# Forgot a name of django app

Tags: python, django

This **app** contains a ton of useful **abstract models**. Maybe someone has a clue what this app name could be?

Comment: You can't be any more specific than that?

Answer (score 2):

```
http://djangopackages.com/categories/apps/
https://launchpad.net/
```

Search here.....

Comment: thanks, already did for many hours yesterday. I'm pretty sure it was on django packages and github.